# Count distinct customers who bought in previous period and not in next period Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset in bigquery which contains order_date: DATE and customer_id.

```
order_date |    CustomerID
2019-01-01 |    111
2019-02-01 |    112
2020-01-01 |    111
2020-02-01 |    113
2021-01-01 |    115
2021-02-01 |    119
```

I try to count distinct customer_id between the months of the previous year and the same months of the current year. For example, from 2019-01-01 to 2020-01-01, then from 2019-02-01 to 2020-02-01, and then who not bought in the same period of next year 2020-01-01 to 2021-01-01, then 2020-02-01 to 2021-02-01.
The output I am expect

```
order_date| count distinct CustomerID|who not buy in the next period
2020-01-01| 5191                     |250
2020-02-01| 4859                     |500
2020-03-01| 3567                     |349
..........| ....                     |......
```

and the next periods shouldn't include the previous.

I tried the code below but it works in another way

```
with customers as (
                  select distinct date_trunc(date(order_date),month) as dates,    
                         CUSTOMER_WID
                  from t 
                  where date(order_date) between '2018-01-01' and current_date()-1
            )
            
            select 
            dates,
            customers_previous,
            customers_next_period
            from 
            (
            select dates,
            count(CUSTOMER_WID) as customers_previous,
            count(case when customer_wid_next is null then 1 end) as customers_next_period,
            from (
            select prev.dates,
            prev.CUSTOMER_WID,
            next.dates as next_dates,
            next.CUSTOMER_WID as customer_wid_next
            from customers as prev
            left join  customers
            as next on next.dates=date_add(prev.dates,interval 1 year) 
            and prev.CUSTOMER_WID=next.CUSTOMER_WID 
            ) as t2
            group by dates
            )
            order by 1,2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any code that we can see representing the code you have tried  or you are asking for help without any time spent on the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the periods using `unnest(generate_date_array())`.  Then use `join`s to bring in the customers from the previous 12 months and the next 12 months.  Finally, aggregate and count the customers:

```
select period,
       count(distinct c_prev.customer_wid),
       count(distinct c_next.customer_wid)
from unnest(generate_date_array(date '2020-01-01', date '2021-01-01', interval '1 month')) period join
     customers c_prev
     on c_prev.order_date <= period and
        c_prev.order_date > date_add(period, interval -12 month) left join
     customers c_next
     on c_next.customer_wid = c_prev.customer_wid and
        c_next.order_date > period and
        c_next.order_date <= date_add(period, interval 12 month)
group by period;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to count values on a window of time, and for that I recommend using window functions - [docs here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts) and [here](https://medium.com/@sonradata/window-function-rows-and-range-on-redshift-and-bigquery-132cbf80c656) a great article explaining how it works.

That said, my recommendation would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    periods,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) OVER 12mos AS count_customers_last_12_mos

FROM (
    SELECT 
        order_date,
        FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m', order_date) AS periods,
        customer_id

    FROM dataset
    )

WINDOW 12mos AS ( # window of last 12 months without current month
    PARTITION BY periods ORDER BY periods DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEEDING AND 1 PRECEEDING 
    )
```

I believe from this you can build some customizations to improve the aggregations you want.